# Unity3D (Android) deeplinking a friend to a open game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, deep-linking

So I have created my first little android-game, and I want the players to have the possibility to invite their friends (those saved in their device's contact-list) to a opened game.

Now such a friend could already have the game already installed on his device, so here I need to send him a deeplink? correct?

There also is the case, where the friend has the game not installed, here he needs to get a link to the game in the playstore.. and maybe, I don't know if it is possible, join the opened game after the installation(?)

Is this possible? if so, .. how? :)

I already looked at how deeplinking in Unity3d works and they say, to enable deeplinking you need to place your own `AndroidManifest.xml` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <application>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="unitydl" android:host="mylink" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

now there is this line `<data android:scheme="unitydl" android:host="mylink" />` .. scheme, ok, that would be what? the game-name? but what is confusing.. what is `host`?? what host? I mean.. I want the players to share the links through email, whatsapp, telegramm & stuff... what host is meant?

can someone please answer me some questions and push me into some direction so I could get this managed?

Answer (score 0):

The actual functionality you are looking for is [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links).
Use a service like [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links?gclid=CjwKCAiAlrSPBhBaEiwAuLSDULRUe0JIakJ5yzmdAPRletiZq67BhoE8nB9xBS-aL8t-E8hO8WNKdhoC160QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) or branch.io to get the expected functionality.

Have a look [here](https://assetstore.essentialkit.voxelbusters.com/deep-link-services/setup) for the details of the parts in a deep link.
Consider you own an website example.com and you want to have a link like https://www.example.com/invite?code=XXX

Now,

scheme = https

host = [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

path = invite?code=xxx

I recommend to use AppLinks(or Universal links on iOS) instead of old deeplinks as its more powerful. The problem with old deeplinks is the schemes you use can't be unique where as with App Links, the domain you own is unique.